# Read .evtx file exported from another machine

Tags: vb.net, event-log

Using VB.net and the code below I can read the local security log.  How do I read the events from an evtx file saved from another computer?

```
Dim elevent As New System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Security", Environment.MachineName)
Dim elEventEntry As System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry

For Each elEventEntry In elevent.Entries
      'Read the event information
Next
```

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say _evtx file saved from another computer_  Is this file being exported from the EventViewer on the other machine and saved in some shared/accessable location or are you meaning connecting directly to the event log on another machine?  If the latter, you've already answered your own question.  Replace Enviroment.MachineName with the machine name you want to inspect.  Of course not taking into account any limitations around security and/or permissions required

Comment: Reading from a file that has been exported from the EventViewer on the other machine and saved in some shared/accessable location.